# WP8 Can't re-select listbox item after using hardware back button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

wp8, C#, VS12

I have a listbox item that when selected/clicked takes the user to anther page...WinePage.xaml

```
    <ListBox
        SelectedIndex="-1"
        SelectionChanged="OpenWinePage_Click"
        x:Name="allItemsListBox" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" 
        Margin="12, 0, 12, 0" Width="440"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WineListBoxItemTemplate}" />
```

When I use WP8's hardware back button to return to the MainPage.xaml, the ListBox I just clicked is no longer selectable/clickable. But I want to be able to go right back to that particular ListBox.

The code in my MainPage.xaml.cs page that takes the user to WinePage.xaml is

```
    private void OpenWinePage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WinePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

What do I need to do to allow the ListBox to be selectable/clickable upon return?

Thanks!

R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the page with your listbox may not destroyed, so when you select an item inside it, the item's state may persists.

try to set its index to -1, then navigate afterwards.

```
allItemsListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

private void OpenWinePage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allItemsListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WinePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: Hi xiriusly,
Thanks for your help... I added the SelectedIndex="-1" to the ListBox (see edited code above), but the ListBox is still unselectable upon return to the page.

Did I add it to the correct area?

Comment: add allItemsListBox.SelectedIndex = -1, in the code behind. , I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks much, xiriusly! Works!